# What's the cheapest way to get your Hungarian salary into a German EUR account?

Tags: banking, foreign-exchange, salary

I get one part of my salary in Hungarian Forints and this cannot be changed.
I live currently in Germany and I need them in Euros. 
Currently I have an account by *Deutsche Bank*, but they use a pretty bad exchange rate when I receive my money. Example:

**2019.12.13**

*Amount*: 738.541 HUF

*Received*: 2200,7 EUR

*Rate DB was using*: 335,69

*Rate on that day*:  330.646 ([source](https://www.poundsterlinglive.com/best-exchange-rates/euro-to-hungarian-forint-exchange-rate-on-2019-12-31))

The difference as the outcome is 33 EUR which I find pretty high (and annoying).
Can you suggest any other method or provider where I could save more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transfer using TransferWise. Done.

Alternatively you could talk to the bank in HUngary and ask for

- Custom exchange rate - but unlikely you get it because your amounts are pathetic comapred to what FIREX desks deal with. I have that here in Poland, but they refuse to exchange less than 9000€ per transaction.
- A EUR account so that you can send the transfer as SEPA

But the mos easy way likely is TransferWise etc. We use Transferwise to pay people in foreign countries - a lot easier than all the alternatives.

5% is  little on the extreme side, but this is how banks operate - no prenegotiation, have fun being ripped off.

Comment: I was thinking about Transferwise as well but: 1. I have no power how my company pays me. I cannot make them to use Transferwise. 2. As far as I know you cannot receive all kind of currencies to your Transerwise account only the following ones: usd, euros, British pounds, New Zealand dollars, Australian dollars, and Polish złoty.
(https://transferwise.com/help/17/borderless-account/2898124/how-do-i-receive-money-into-my-account)

Comment: "1. I have no power how my company pays me. " - sorry? Open account in Hungary, take the FLoring there, issue transfer to Transferwise yourself. You sound like you can not open a bank accout. That is wrong. 2: Do not use them as bank account. Use the transfer service.

Comment: You are right: checked the money transfer with the same amount with todays exchange rate (which is much higher as of the date I posted: 338) and it costs: 
9.77 EUR. The Hungarian bank account monthly costs around 2 EUR pro month so this is an absolute win of 23 EUR. Thank you.

Comment: With the amount in your question, you can easily get a premium account in Hungary, which have lower or even zero fees.

Comment: The only question is if it is possible to open an account in Hungary if you are not a resident. If you aren't, it might be possible to open an account with Deutsche Bank in Hungarian currency, but I am not sure if this reduces the costs in a significant way.

Comment: "The only question is if it is possible to open an account in Hungary if you are not a resident" Hungary is in the EU and EEC. It is totally possible to open accounts in other countries.